# PyQT: How to search Widget Items by Data

Tags: python, pyqt

With each `for i in range(3):` iteration a ComboBox Item and QTreeWidget Item is created. An instance variable of MyClass() is declared and it is assigned to .setData() for both ComboBox and TreeWidget item (so the items point to the same variable/object).

Selecting a ComboBox's or Tree's item prints the item's dataObeject's ID number.

The question: It is quite clear how to search Combobox if the item's name is known.

```
resultIndex = comboBox.findText('Items Name')
```

But how to search for a Combobox's item by item's data? So the goal: we select Tree's item, we read selected item's .data(). Knowing one of the comoBoxe's items has the same data object we search Combobox for an item with a corresponding .data object:  (comboItem.data()==treeItem.data).

How to do it without using `for i in range(self.comboBox.count()): and etc`

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sys, os

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__()     

class myWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        myLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.comboBox = QtGui.QComboBox()        
        self.tree = QtGui.QTreeWidget()
        myLayout.addWidget(self.comboBox)
        myLayout.addWidget(self.tree)

        for i in range(3):
            myObject=MyClass()
            self.comboBox.addItem('Item '+str(i), myObject)

            item=QtGui.QTreeWidgetItem()
            item.setText(0, 'Item '+str(i))
            item.setData(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole, myObject)
            self.tree.addTopLevelItem(item)

        self.comboBox.activated.connect(self.comboActivated)
        self.tree.clicked.connect(self.treeItemClicked)

    def comboActivated(self, itemNumber=None):
        itemData=self.comboBox.itemData(itemNumber).toPyObject()
        print 'Comobox Data Object ID =', id(itemData)

    def treeItemClicked(self, itemIndex=None):
        item=self.tree.itemFromIndex(itemIndex)
        itemData=item.data(0, QtCore.Qt.UserRole).toPyObject()
        print 'TreeWid Data Object ID =', id(itemData)

        # HOW TO SEARCH COMBOBOX ITEMS TO FIND A CORRESPONDING DATA OBJECT?

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setApplicationName('myApp')
    dialog = myWindow()
    dialog.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Why not just use the same index number for both (assuming they hold the same list of data in the same order)?

Comment: Good idea! But unfortunately in a real world scenario the items order will be different. We can't rely on it.